# Applying a method onto all instances of class inside a list

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I am picking up C# and as a beginners exercise I tried to code a simple Tekken Tournament roster. The problem is, that I cannot find a way how to apply a method of class `Fighter` onto the whole list of fighters, as there are no names of the variable, or at least I think that is the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TekkenConsoleTournament
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Enter nicknames of players, finished by 0: \n");
            int numFighter=0;
            String nickname;
            List <Fighter> allFighters = new List<Fighter>();
            while ((nickname = Console.ReadLine()) != "") {
                allFighters.Add(new Fighter(nickname));
                numFighter ++;

            }
            Console.WriteLine(allFighters.ForEach(Fighter.getName()));

            Console.WriteLine(foreach(Fighter in allFighters) {getName();}); 

            //for (int counter = 0; counter <= fighter; counter++) {
            //  Fighter[counter.getName();
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

And the Fighter.cs

```
using System;

namespace TekkenConsoleTournament
{
    public class Fighter
    {
        private int matches, won, lost, draw;
        String name;
        public Fighter (String name)
        {
            this.matches = this.won = this.lost = 0;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void wonMatch()
        {
            matches++;won++;

        }
        public void lostMatch()
        {
            matches++;lost++;

        }

        public void drawMatch()
        {
            matches++;draw++;

        }

        public int[] getStats()
        {
            int[] stats = {this.matches,this.won,this.lost,this.draw};
            return stats;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}
```

At first, I d like to print the names of all fighters, then maybe the stats and then as an exercise try making the code remember who fought who and put them in two dimensional matrix based on the result of the fight.

Comment: can you provide your Fighter class ? And what exactly do you want, show names of all fighters ?

Comment: You want to put the Console.WriteLine code inside the foreach loop.

Comment: A few pointers (conventions): Classes, method names, and property names should be PascalCased (i.e. public void DrawMatch()). Methods which only get/set a value should usually be properties (i.e. public String getName() should be public String Name{ get { return this.name; } }. You can (and *I* would say *should*) use `string` instead of `String` (just as you use `int` rather than `Int32`

Comment: Hmm.. Is there any particular reason why is that? From my fiddling with Java I got used to upper-case S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `foreach` loop ?

```
foreach(var fighter in allFighters)
{
    // do something with fighter
    var name = fighter.getName();
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

I assume there is a `getName` method, if there is not use your `field` or `property` name to get current fighter's name.

Your mistake is you are putting `ForEach` loops inside of `Console.WriteLine` method.You should do the opposite.And this syntax is wrong:

```
foreach(Fighter in allFighters)
```

It should be like this:

```
foreach(Fighter fighter in allFighters)
```

Or you can use `var` as shown in the above code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I thought, that if I didn't set up the name of variable beforehand, I couldn't work with it in that manner. With your addition, it all works. After I finish it, I will post the completed code here.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but not quite. Try these options:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", allFighters.Select(f => f.getName())));

allFighters.ForEach(fighter => Console.Writeline(fighter.getName()));


foreach (Fighter f in allFighters)
{
    Console.WriteLine(f.getName());
}
```